# Chef MySql Cookbook: MySql does not start after reboot

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, chef-infra, vagrant

I'm trying to install mysql recipe in vagrant. I use [this](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/mysql) cookbook for that.

MySql service starts after `vagrant up`, but after reboot I can't perform neither `vagrant provision` or `vagrant up`, because the server fails to start.

I have realized, that Vagrant wipes `/var/run` directory; it creates mysqld directory (for socket), but not mysql (for pid file). MySql can't find the directory and can't create pid file.

How can I make it work? Why Vagrant creates mysqld, but not mysql?

I also tried it with different boxes (precise32, cloud daily precise64).

Box: http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box
Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise32"
  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest

  config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8000, host: 8080

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.gui = true
  end
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = "./chef-repo/cookbooks"
    chef.add_recipe "apt"
    chef.add_recipe "mysql::server"
    chef.json = {
      "mysql" => {
                  "server_root_password" => "password",
                  "server_repl_password" => "password",
                  "server_debian_password" => "password"
                 }
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: `/var/run` is a symbolic link to `/run` which is `tmpfs` in-memory filesystem. It does NOT survive reboots. I don't think it has anything to do with vagrant. Simple reboot the VM, you lose everything in it.

Comment: That is correct. I have changed the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in MySql cookbook: somehow /var/run/mysqld is not wiped, so the workaround would be: change in `<mysql_cookbook>/libraries/provider_mysql_service_ubuntu.rb`

```
pid_file = '/var/run/mysql/mysql.pid'
```

to

```
pid_file = '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid'
```

I make also an issue on github, so in the future the bug could be fixed in master

Comment: Here is an issue filed for this bug: https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/COOK-4519

Answer (score 0):

eviltnan is correct. Here's a scripted workaround for a first run ubuntu 12.04.

```
ruby_block "ensure mysql server starts on reboot" do
  block do
    fe = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/etc/mysql/my.cnf")
    fe.search_file_replace_line(/pid-file/, 'pid-file                       = /var/run/mysqld/mysql.pid')
    Chef::Log.warn("Edited /etc/mysql/my.cnf to re-enable start on reboot.") if fe.write_file
  end
end
```